# Support both 32 & 64 bit iOS binary without code changes in Xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I wanted to check if its possible to build iOS app with both 32-bit and 64-bit support without using the new Unified Apis in Xamarin. Unified API support will require code changes in existing Xamarin iOS apps which are using MonoTouch Foundation and we want to avoid that.

Any pointers will be welcome

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

No it is not possible to support 64 bit apps with the classic API. This is explained in the Xamarin blog post: http://blog.xamarin.com/unified-api-with-64-bit-support-for-ios-and-mac/

It is actually quite easy to update to unified, so i don't see a reason why you want to avoid that, also because it will be a requirement of Apple soon, and you can't publish new updates anymore after there deadline. For more information on how to update see the Xamarin documentation on that: http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/macios/updating_ios_apps/

Comment: Hi Martijn, thanks for the reply. I want to upgrade the code to support 64 bit but I dont want code changes (like changing MonoTouch apis to Foundation apis). In case of native app, its simply an Xcode configuration but in Xamarin it looks like it involves code changes. I think Xamarin should have decoupled these 2 features in the latest release: support for 64 bit and having an Unified API for Mac and iOS.

Comment: Maybe they should have done that, but that is their decision. I think there is no other solution for this currently then to upgrade to unified, so you get x64 support.